# Installing Windows 98 using a USB CD-ROM drive

Tags: windows, usb, windows-installation, optical-drive, windows-98

I'm trying to install Windows 98 on an old Dell [Optiplex FX160 thinclient](https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_desktop/esuprt_optiplex_desktop/optiplex-fx160_service%20manual_en-us.pdf) that does not have an optical drive. Because it doesn't have one, I'm using a cheap [Lite-On DS8ACSH](http://www.liteonodd.com/en/dvd-internal/item/dvdinternal/ds-8acsh.html) optical drive in a USB enclosure. Unfortunately, even though the Windows 98 disc boots fine, as soon as it tries to start setup or enter the command line it will fail to load the CD-ROM driver (no device found) and I cannot continue.

Is there any way to make this drive work under DOS so that I can run Windows 98 setup?

Comment: Please note that I'd love to just go out and pick up some old Pentium 2/3 whatever gray box and use that instead, it's just that with covid-19 roaming around this is all I have got available to me. I just want to play some windows 98 games that don't work well in VM's!

Comment: Looks like there's only one SATA port on the motherboard, so taking the LiteOn ODD out of the USB enclosure and attaching it to the Optiplex motherboard is a no go. You therefore need DOS drivers for the ODD. Does the USB Enclosure vendor provide that driver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the hard drive in this system is visible by DOS.

If the hard drive is big enough, move/connect the hard drive to a system where the CD-ROM drive can be accessed temporarily, and then try copying the entire Windows 98 CD-ROM to it.

Put the hard drive back into the system you want to install, boot DOS from USB and enter the command line, CD to the C: drive and then run the Windows98 setup.exe from the hard drive.

I don't think the setup.exe cares what drive the files exist on as long as it's the same as where you run the setup.exe from.

Also if your hard drive is SATA, and visible to DOS, try taking the optical drive out of the enclosure and connecting to second SATA port on the motherboard (if it exists).

Comment: Hadn't yet thought of copying over the entire disc to the drive, and like you mentioned I doubt Windows 98 cares about the location of its files anyways. Do you think it would also be possible to do this by booting linux off USB and copying everything over in that environment?

Comment: Copy the cabs folder on the Windows 98 CD to the disk you want to install it on (I assume formatted) to a folder you make called c:\windows\options\cabs.   From the cabs folder, run Setup and Windows 98 will install.

Comment: I used to use a simpler method – just copy the entire CD into C:\INSTALL.WIN or whatever similar directory. The installer indeed doesn't seem to care. IIRC, copying to disk was pretty much _required_ when installing Win95 (which didn't load CD drivers during the second phase)...

Comment: This is exactly what I did back in the day. Had Win98 on a second partition and a DOS boot disk for when Windows inevitably killed itself. A boot from DOS, a quick format and reinstall from hard disk by running setup.exe was easy to do.

Comment: Yes this is the best solution, done it many times.

Comment: Ended up copying over the cd contents to the hdd directly using a ubuntu livecd, then I booted the setup using a freedos stick. After some additional tweaks (ignore scandisk, hi memory manager) I managed to install Windows 98 succesfully. Thanks a lot!